# Is there a way to update a scrollspy dropdown's text when it is not spying on anything to a default text?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue and am using Bootstrap Vue Scrollspy(https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/scrollspy#example-using-navs). My dropdown is sticky and is spying on all the content referenced. The sticky dropdown has a text that updates with the current section in view.

This is like my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-tree-1w3hx?file=/src/App.vue

Is there any way I can set the text of my dropdown to a default text like from the link above it is "Contents"? So that every time the scrollspying is done, it just turns the text of the dropdown to a default text? What I do not like about this approach is that I need a height property on `#nav-scroller` and since I am dealing with dynamic data, I don't see this as an option for me. The double scrollbars are also something I do not want.

I tried to make the dropdown sticky in my code by using Stickybits(https://dollarshaveclub.github.io/stickybits/), I also tried checking up if they had a feature where I can get an event fired when the position is not sticky then the text of the dropdown changes to the default text, but from my research, I don't think they do?

In addition, I have tried doing an overflow hidden but that doesn't solve the issue.

I am trying to find a way through which this is achievable without jQuery. Would appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: First of all, show us what you tried. Create a [mcve]. Because so far you've shown examples which seem to do what you want and you also linked some docs/libs. But you haven't shown what is the specific error/problem you're facing. What's keeping you from replicating those examples and/or using those libs? Last, but not least, please define what you call *"pure html, css and js"* (or impure, if it's simpler) so we could understand what you want.

Comment: Hey Tao, thank you for your answer to my previous question. I'm sorry that my question was not clear, but the link to the code is exactly how my code is but just that it is with dynamic data. I don't really see dynamic data to work well with heights which causes the double scrollbar. And no the code doesn't seems to do what I want :( just trying to find a solution without the use of the height property or achieve the same purpose on the basis of some event that is fired by Bootstrap Vie Scrollspy when it's "not scrollspying". I have also updated my question, thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 4):

Took me a bit to understand the requirement, but you seem to want a custom dropdown button text when there is no section selected. To make things easy to control, I made it completely DRY:

- i placed an `emptySectionMessage` and a `defaultDropdownText` in `data`
- i created a `dropdownText` computed property which returns `sectionTitle` when scrollspy has a target or `defaultDropdownText` otherwise.

Feel free to change the data prop values to whatever you need.

See it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-montalcini-bexqu?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Yep, that was my requirement :) Thanks for the answer. According to the code I shared, I do have some text above the dropdown itself. Now when I place that text there, we have the same double scrollbar issue again :(

Comment: No, ***"we don't have"*** the same double scrollbar issue. ***"You have"*** the same double scrollbar issue. For two reasons: 1) It has absolutely nothing to do with this question. 2) I already fixed it in my answer. The "fix" is not to have anything above or below the scroll container. You put it inside the scrollspy container. That's how scrollspy works. You put something above/below? You have to deduct it from its height (`100vh - X`). Or you get a double scrollbar. And if you don't set a height on it, back to square one: it simply does not work, because it's no longer a scroll container.

Comment: An alternative is to distance the scrollspy container enough from the `<body>`. As an example, using a `.container` inside a `.container-fluid`. However, on narrow devices (below `768px`), you have to disable scrollspy (or include everything else in it - which is pretty much what I suggested above). Otherwise: double scrollbar. But really, that's a completely different question. You have to ask it separately so that anyone with the same problem might benefit from any potential answer. I can't answer it here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ideas and the explanation, I just happen to have less experience than you in this regard and yes **I have** the double scrollbar issue. :) Regardless, I appreciate the effort and will accept this answer if it works at this end! :) Many thanks.

Comment: @Alyssa, internet has this funny way of stripping a lot from communication. I said all of the above without any sort of negative feelings or intentions. On the contrary. But I'm aware it's easily possible to interpret it that way (hence the clarification). You're most welcome. :) Happy coding!